# selectItem not selecting cells if they are near to current selected cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently working on an UIViewController with a horizontal collectionView on top with days of the week for the next few months (like a calendar) and below it i've got a tableView with the next events happening near the user's location. 
When a user scrolls down the table view it gets the top cell event date and scrolls the collectionView to that day. I'm using the following code:

**On tableView's cellForRowAt :**

```
datePicker.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
```

**On collectionView's cellForItemAt :**

```
if cell.isSelected {

            cell.selectedCircle.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            cell.selectedCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:0.08, blue:0.35, alpha:1)
            cell.weekDayLabel.alpha = 1
            selectedMonth.text = dateToday.3.firstUppercased


        } else {

            cell.selectedCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1, green:0.08, blue:0.35, alpha:0)
            cell.weekDayLabel.alpha = 0.4
        }
```

Everything works perfectly when the next collectionView IndexPath to select is far from the previous one. When they are around 8 or below indexPaths apart, collectionView scrolls to the right indexPath but doesn't run the isSelected code.

Any idea? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're storing isSelected information inside the cell.  Don't.  You could be getting a cell that was previously somewhere else and recycled.  Keep the logic of which cells are selected inside something else (like an array), and look it up based on the index path.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Owen. I think i understand what you're saying, just not quite sure how to do it. So tableView cell keeps the .selectItem function, then stores the collectionView target cell indexpath on an array. I've got that covered, just not sure whre to go from there. Could you please give me a help. Thank you.

Comment: Store the selected cells outside of the collection view, in your own private array or other structure.  Those cells get reused, or you'll be creating a new one.  When you get called in your cellForItemAt: method, look up in your array whether the cell should be selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I had a UICollectionView with horizontal scroll and paging.

It all worked fine, as long as I wasn't calling selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:) on a cell that was not one of the first 2 cells on the next page or the last 2 on the previous page.

The problem seems to be that isSelected is not being set. And cellForItem(at:) wasn't called either (I think because the cell was in fact, already loaded).

Here's my fix. I subclass the UICollectionView and override contentOffset to be notified when the cell might become visible and then set isSelected manually.

```
override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
    didSet {
        self.refreshVisibleCells()
    }
}

func refreshVisibleCells() {
    for cell in self.visibleCells {
        let cell = cell as! CalendarViewCell
        if cell.date == self.selectedDate {
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}
```